# Pandas installation on VScode (Mac)

Tags: python, pandas, macos, modulenotfounderror

I am new on python and have been stuck on this issue since yesterday evening. I have tried everything I found on internet. I updated the version of python too.
so numpy works fine but pandas just doesn't. Also for the newer version of python, the path isn't same in vscode vs mac terminal. Does that create any issue? if so how do i solve?
[This shows on problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhPDg.png)
pandas installed cause it says "requirement already satisfied" but while running the program it says: [ModuleNotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHhg6.png)

My patience is just about to go zero..

I tried:

1. trashing and reinstalling newer version i was using 3.11 so i got 3.12
2. virtual env
3. works for numpy

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: how many instances of python do you have on your computer? It might be that the "akready installed" is for 1 version of python but the one VS code is using is a second instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script as below and run in vscode:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

You will get something like this as a result: /usr/bin/python

That is the path of python that vscode uses.

Now, you should stick to only that particular python environment for simplicity. Ignore other environments you have installed.

Then, do the following command to install pandas:

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install pandas
```

Ensure that the part before "-m" is the same as the output of the script earlier.